# Updating plone addons on several sites at once

Tags: plone

I have a plone instance containing several plone sites. 
Whenever I upgrade plone (ex. from 4.2.1 to 4.2.3) there are some addons which need to be updated as well. My own local products need to be updated from time to time as well.

I usually go into the zmi quickinstaller folder reinstall them one by one. However having 18 plone sites in this particular plone instance means that now I have to update the addons for every site manually.

Is there a product or script which would automate the update of products/addons?

Comment: Refs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30499063/how-do-i-prevent-values-of-custom-registry-entries-to-be-overwritten-on-reinstal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addon [ftw.upgrade](https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.upgrade) provides a view (@@manage-upgrades) which lists all addon-upgrades for this plone site (in an order based on dependencies) and you can upgrade all addons for one plone site with a single click. Scripting APIs and upgrading of multiple sites are in development. Upgrading the plone version is not supported, that's the job of the plone migration tool.

The addon [collective.upgrade](https://github.com/collective/collective.upgrade) does a similar job and has already scripting support and I think it can also upgrade plone sites, not just addons.